# Creating a Wordpress masonry style gallery with a lightbox that only cycles through images with the same category/tag

Tags: wordpress, gallery, lightbox, categories, masonry

I am trying to create a Wordpress image gallery which does a few things that no one plugin seems to do on its own.

Basically I want to:
1. split the media library into categories/albums
2. display every image from those albums mixed together on the same page in a masonry style layout (An image from category a, then an image from category b, then an image from category c etc etc)
3. bring up a lightbox when an image is clicked that only cycles through images from the same category

The difficulty is that I'm not sure where to begin, so I'm looking for some ideas on how I should approach it. Would starting with a plugin which separates the media library into categories/albums be a good place to start? Could the native Wordpress masonry/tiled gallery and lightbox be adapted to do the rest?

Update: I've registered new taxonomy which applies to attachments, so the images now belong to categories

Really sorry for not giving a better starting point!

Answer (score 0):

To sum my understanding of what you need: You need posts, with attached images that belong to categories.

Replying to your points:

1. Forget about splitting the media library;
2. You just loop through the posts;
3. You install a simple lightbox gallery plugin and only loop the posts you need.

To accomplish this:

1. Register a custom post type (which I saw you already did);
2. Create your custom posts, associate the images and give them a category;
3. Install masonry (doesn't matter the way it looks right now) and loop the featured images;
4. With a lightbox plugin, pass the ID of the clicked item, go get the category and loop it so users can check the images of the same categories.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I haven't replied until now as I'm still working on it! Everything you said seems to work out though so I'll come back and give you correct answer when I nail it! The only thing that may be missing is how I jumble up the images within the masonry layout so they don't just display in ascending or descending order, but I'll tackle that when I get there. Thanks again!